# How to shift cell after select it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I'm locking for the solution in the method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: UIIndexPath) {
}
```

After I select a Row it should change the color and move to the End of the Array, the other one should move up

Comment: Do you need to apply animation when move up or down?

Answer (score 0):

To move the row down, you can do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: UIIndexPath) {
    //move selected cell down to last row
    tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath:NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1, inSection: indexPath.section))
}
```

For changing the color see [How to change color of UITableViewCell when selecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265662/how-to-change-color-of-uitableviewcell-when-selecting)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and its so simple, I've searched for the solutions since few days :)

Answer (score 0):

For data consistency you have to move the item in the table and the data source array respectively.

`dataSourceArray` represents the data source array

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  let itemToMove = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
  dataSourceArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
  dataSourceArray.append(itemToMove)

  let destinationIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: dataSourceArray.count - 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
  tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath:destinationIndexPath)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tipp, but if I have a lot of elements in my array and don't see the last one, click the first, it moves to the end of the array and become gray background, but if I scroll down and see the last element and then pick one bevor the last it move down rightly without changing the color. Do you now why its happened??

Comment: Scrolling recalls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` explicitly. You might add a line to reload this particular row if it's visible.

Comment: maybe an approach, I'm a little bit desperately