# Highlight a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to highlight some cells in my tableView. By highlighting I mean setting the background color of the cell to the blue color used for example when copying a text. I used tried this code to check if it works

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        cell.setHighlighted(true, animated: false)
    }
```

I also tried this

```
cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
```

In both cases the cells become grey and not blue. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Have you tried to set the cell's `selectionStyle` to `blue`?

Answer (score 4):

> Change the **selectionStyle** property of yourcell. If you want to change it to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`, it will be **blue**. for alternate method , you can get the another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265662/how-to-change-color-of-uitableviewcell-when-selecting)

for e.g

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
cell.selectionStyle = .blue
}
```

`UITableViewCell` has three default selection styles:-

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellSelectionStyle) {
UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone,
UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue,
UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray,
UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
};
```

or you can directly set the `Selection color` in your cell class like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        cell.selectionStyle = .blue
    }
```